# Weird white arrow on Word 2013 document

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

The following image is a screenshot from MS Word 2013

[image]

The two paragraphs, beginning at **"Similar to those of immobilized assets..."** are preceded by weird white arrows. What are they? What can I do to take them off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Weird white arrows. What are they? What can I do to take them off?

They are Expand Icons (next to a heading that has been Collapsed) and they cannot be removed.

Click on it will expand the Heading to show what is "contained" in the Heading.

---

#### Expand And Collapse In Word 2013

> Word 2013 introduces a new feature that allows you to expand and
>   collapse certain parts of your document. It reminds me very much of
>   the kind of web page interactivity that lets you click on a brief
>   summary of something to display a more detailed description. And
>   that’s precisely what this is.
>
> If you can’t visualise this concept, let’s illustrate it with a simple
>   example. Create a new blank document in Word 2013 and create a heading
>   1 followed by some text. To quickly create some random text, you can
>   type in =rand(5, 5) and press Enter to create five paragraphs each of
>   five lines. Now create a heading 2 followed by more text. When you
>   hover over any heading, you will see an arrow pointing in a particular
>   direction, and the direction tells us whether clicking on it will
>   expand or collapse what is below the heading.
>
> This arrow, when clicked, collapses the content below the heading:
>
> [image: Collapse In Word 2013]
>
> This is what the heading looks like after the collapse arrow has been
>   clicked:
>
> [image: Expand In Word 2013]
>
> You can see that everything below the heading has been collapsed and
>   only the heading is now displayed. This is a convenient way of hiding
>   content you don’t want to see so you only see the outline of the
>   document. If you want to read the content, just click on the arrow
>   again.
>
> The expand/collapse arrows don’t necessarily affect everything below
>   their header. They only affect the content below the header and up to
>   the next header of equal or greater value.
>
> ...
>
> There is a quick way to expand or collapse all headings in your
>   document; right click on a heading > Expand/Collapse, and select
>   Expand all Headings or Collapse all Headings.
>
> [image: Expand All Headings]
>
> When you open a document, all headings are expanded by default.

Source [Expand And Collapse In Word 2013](http://www.word-2013-tutorials.com/expand-and-collapse-in-word-2013/)