# Microsoft Word: Collapsible Arrow can not be removed, even after switching to a normal style

Tags: microsoft-word, styles

My document has somehow ended up filled with these collapsible arrows. They don't hide or reveal anything, but it seems every second line (where I've entered then indented) is being treated as a heading. And yes, I've checked my styles. All text is being read as using the "normal" style

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Weird white arrow on Word 2013 document](https://superuser.com/questions/1101843/weird-white-arrow-on-word-2013-document)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] center. Here is a guide on [ask] and [answer].

Comment: Please publish online your document for us to examine (OneDrive, Dropbox etc). (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: When you go to the "View" tab and activate the navigation pane, does the navigation pane contain text from these paragraphs that have the collapsible arrow next to it?